# React Router Sending Props

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a router config like this:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/">
        <IndexRoute component={HomePageContainers} />
        <Route path="r/:subreddit_name" component={Subreddit} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

`HomePageContainers` renders like:

```
render() {

    return (<div>
        <HomePage reddits={this.state.reddits} key={this.state.isLoaded && this.state.reddits.data.after} isLoaded={this.state.isLoaded} isScrolling={this.state.isScrolling} scrollFunc={this.onScroll.bind(this)} />
    </div>)
}
```

and `HomePage` render `Reddits` like:

```
 <Col md={3} key={reddit.data.id}>
   <Reddits key={reddit.data.id} reddit={reddit}/><br/>
 </Col>
```

There is a `Reddits` class which looks like:

```
class Reddits extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        let reddit = this.props.reddit;
        return(
            <div id={styles.box}>
                <p>{reddit.data.title}</p>
                <Link to={reddit.data.url}>
                    <p>{reddit.data.url}</p>
                </Link>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

whenever the path is `r/:subreddit_name` made, `Subreddit` component gets life and its working. Here I also get the `:subreddit_name` value as part of `routeParams`. But if you look at the `Reddits` class, the `reddit.data` has all the information for `Subreddit`.

I want to send the `reddit.data` as props from `Route(r)`, is it possible?

Comment: How are the two related? There is no `Reddits` component in the router.

Comment: @Pavlo: We need to design routing based on relations too? I'm sorry starting fresh on react router!

Comment: You have to mount `Reddits` somewhere. AFAIK, you can't pass arbitrary data through the router, so you'll probably need a store.

Comment: Yeah. Sounds like you need a store of some sort, try [tag:relayjs] or [tag:redux]

Comment: @Pavlo: `Reddits` is mounted and rendered via `HomePageContainers`.

Comment: Could you post `HomePageContainers` code too?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to have HomeComponenet render your Reddit component as children like so:

```
<Route path='/home' component="HomeComponent">
  <Route path='/reddit' component="RedditComponent">
</Route>
```

To get reddit component to display you need to render children in your `HomeComp`:

```
render() {
  { this.props.children }
}
```

Now you can pass in props via cloning children like so:

`HomeComp`:

```
render() {
       {this.props.children && React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
              someFunctionOrDataToPass: this.someFunctionOrDataToPass
            })}
    }
```

[Here is another example](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/examples/passing-props-to-children/app.js)